# How do I get all the computer's space available?

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

I got an Ubuntu 20.04 in a computer with these specs:

[image]

My computer's disc usage is divided like this:

[image]

As you can see, almost all of the *Computer* section's space is used, while *500 GB Volume* section has plenty to spare. However, it is read-only. Why is this? Is it possible to make that section usable the same way as *Computer* section? Is that a good idea, and if so, how do I do that?

EDIT:
Before I installed Ubuntu this computer had Windows 10. But I have assumed so far that it was replaced completely. I can't tell if it has more than one hard drive. It's just supposed to be a regular computer, I haven't added any external drives.**strong text**

Also, The *volume* section contains two folders: *$RECYCLE.BIN* and *System Volume Information*.

Comment: How is that 500GB volume formatted, and how is it mounted?  Maybe the fstab contains some clues as to why it is read-only.

Comment: This really depends on how you configured your own system, and you haven't given us enough details to understand. Clearly there is more than one volume. Is there more than one hard drive?  Or are there multiple partitions on a single hard drive? Do you dual boot with another operating system?  Please edit your question with the answers to these followup questions and also include any other details that we should know about the configuration of your hard drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shrunk the size 500 GB Volume and created a new partition from the leftover space I can use freely.

Comment: I can only hope this won't come bite me and 50 GB will be enough for whatever the Volume was originally meant for.

Answer (score 0):

[image]500GB Volume is probably writable for root user only.
To make it writable for your user, install gnome-disk-utility:

```
sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility
```

Run it (Accesories->Disks), assign this disk and click button "Additional partition options". Select option "Take ownership" from menu.

Edit: added screenshot

Edit: Alternatively you may run in terminal:

```
sudo gio set -t uint32 /dev/sdb1 unix::uid 1000
```

Comment: I can't find Take Ownership.

Comment: Sorry, it's just not there. There's nothing between repair filesystem and edit mount options.

Comment: Sorry, tried that command but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to interpret the picture carefully.

The Top row which says Computer means you've consumed 2.5 GB out of 125 GB available on '/'

This '/' means the root directory for your Ubuntu machine.  You have lots of space available here.

Separately, you have a 500 GB volume which is mounted on '/dev/sdb1'

This might be an external USB drive, or it could be another partition on the disk where you've got your root directory.

Between the two you have 120 + 500 or 620 GB of space to use.

A good way to explore your system and its files might be to click on the "Home" icon in the sidebar on the left.